# WPF image source gif animation

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I get the GIF animated to work with the code below? The problem is the image will change accordinly to few different image.

WPF:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ElementName=L, Path=Image}" Height="400" Width="600" Stretch="None" />
```

Code behind:
 public readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty;

```
    public ImageSource ImageStatus
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/L;component/Images/test.gif", UriKind.Relative));
```

---

EDITED:

http://eladm.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/animated-gif-support-behavior/

Comment: I've googled "wpf animated gif" and found [this](http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/)

Comment: thanks found that, but sometime I want to put in png file as well, I want to pass in the value using the method above.

Comment: That won't work. As you might have already realized, setting the `Source` property will *not* magically animate the image. There is no built-in support for animated GIFs in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this to make my `gifs` work: http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_animated_gif.php

**[edit]**

I have found something for `WPF`: http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/

But I didn't test it!

Comment: Are you using WPF Image source?

Comment: The vcskicks link uses PictureBox, so is a WinForms solution.